# GNU sed for windows handling special characters

Tags: windows, sed, character

I am running the GNU sed 4.2.1 implementation for Windows but no experience with sed.

I have an xml file with line in this format:

`<field level="document" name="Title" value="Pericles" />`

Need to convert each line to this:

`<entry key="cm:Title">Pericles</entry>`

Tried many things for many hours but although quotes problem is solved (quote-backslash-quote-quote), greater than character '>' slash , less than char, cause problems.

'>' should be treated as any other character, correct? But no, this implementation seems to asssume file redirection.

Tried to use backslash, caret etc but authough I am almost there, it fails.

Also noticed several samples from Unix, fail in Windows.Is Windowsa different implementation or has to do with OS?

Anyone used sed for Windows and can help me?

Comment: You claim to be "almost there". Then why don't you specify exactly where you are, so someone may help you with the last (few) step(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing xml would be made a lot easier with tools like `xmlstarlet` etc.

That said, you *could* attempt this with Unix tools like `sed`, `awk` etc.

With `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r '/^<field/s/.*name="([^"]+)".*value="([^"]+)".*/<entry key="cm:\1">\2<\/entry>/' file.txt
```

With `GNU awk`:

```
awk '/^<field/ { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i ~ /^name=/) { name = substr($i, 7) } if ($i ~ /^value=/) { value = substr($i, 8, length($i) - 8) } }  printf "<entry key=\"cm:%s>%s</entry>\n", name, value }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
<entry key="cm:Title">Pericles</entry>
```

Comment: Seems my comment cannot be displayed properly. I ran sed command and got error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '''`
Replaced single with double quotes and got the error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 68: invalid reference \2 on 's' command's RHS`

Comment: @chora: I'm no windows guru, but you may want to consider running `sed` on a linux-like environment like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: Thanks Steve, this can be difficult, as the procedure must run unattended on a regular basis. I think I must look at Windows Powershell for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, may help someone looking for this.
use double quotes instead of single quotes

sed -e "s/ text with > / /g" works for me in cmd.exe using Cygwin sed.